# Maxymiser help Script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I must work on Oracle MaxyMiser for make some changes into one site. 
I've already tryied to modify the Html and it's more or less clear for me how make change from this section. 
 Now I see there is another section inside the Maxymiser panel for make some changes. 
 This section is the script section. 
 I don't understand how this section works. 
 I tryied to change one css property of one html div without succes.

This is how I try to change one proprety:

```
  var salesAmount;
  salesAmount = jQuery('#regionForm')[0];
  console.log(salesAmount);
  console.log(salesAmount.style.display); --> "" 
  console.log(salesAmount.css);  --> undefined
  //salesAmount.style.display = "block"; --> doen't work
});
```

Here I tryied to change the css display property without success ( the div already have one property display:none setted from the original css rule ). 
I would like to open one modal already present into the html from one script and chage some css class or properties. 
Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After several tests I was able to add a custom script from the appropriate section. 
In order to connect a click action to a custom button added via a variant of MaxyMiser I had to work through the window.onload function. 
An example of js I added:

```
//insert script code here
window.onload = function(){
    const btn_close = document.querySelector(".class-button");
    const banner = document.querySelector("#idDiv");

    btn_close.addEventListener('click', function(){
        banner.classList.add('hidden');
    },false); 
};
```

I hope this can help someone.

Bye